# A numpy function convert list(tuple) of byte seires (with equal length) to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to convert a huge list of tuple of bytes to a numeric numpy.ndarray in a data processing task. The list, with the length of **over 10 Millions**, consists of tuples containing 3 450-bytes series, which looks like the example below

```py
[
    (
        b'\n\x0f\n\t\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x07\x06...', # 450 bytes series
        b'\x00\x0e\x00\x06\x07\x0c\n\x0e\x07...', # also 450 bytes
        b'\x05\x0e\x07\t\x04\x01\x05\x07\x08...',
    ), # 3-byte-serie tuple
    (...), # more tuples like this
    ... # the number of tuples is up to 10M
]
```

What I hope to get is a **numpy.uint8 array** with the shape of (10Ms, 3, 450), in which each uint8 element is corresponding to a byte in the series (e.g. `b'\n\x0f\n\t'` to [10, 15, 10, 9]).

Or to be simple, I'm looking for a opposite function of element-wise `numpy.ndarray.tobytes`

Of course this can be realized with a simple iteration written with `for` in raw python, convert the byte series to 1-dimension array with `numpy.fromiter` one by one. But due to the huge amount of data, I hope use numpy to accelerate the process as much as possible. So what I want is a direct numpy function, or code with a few numpy functions without any raw python `for` iteration.

p.s. I've also tried to combine `numpy.fromiter` with `np.frompyfunc` and use it on the numpy array of bytes generate with `np.array(..., dtype = object)`, but it still doesn't seem fast enough.

Comment: Could you comment on how you're getting the list of tuple of bytes? Once the data is scattered among millions of objects around the heap, there's not much numpy can do other than iterate the Python objects, same as you would with a for loop. That's your main obstacle in terms of performance. Do you think there's any way to switch to using a dense representation earlier?

Comment: They came from tables in several SQLite databases (200+ database with hundreds of tables containing hundreds x 3 of such 450-length bytes), so I'm afraid its hard to achieve your idea. @Brian61354270

Comment: However, the databases are also create by myself, and the 450-length bytes are dumped to save some 60x60 binary figures generated from different objects in a python simulator. So things may be better if I can change the way I save the figures?

Comment: I've set up [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77697159/savingreading-binary-figures-tofrom-sqlite-database-with-python) for the read&write problem above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `np.frombuffer` might be what your are looking for:

```py
import numpy as np

data = [
    (
        b'\n\x0f\n\t\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x07\x06', # 450 bytes series
        b'\x00\x0e\x00\x06\x07\x0c\n\x0e\x07', # also 450 bytes
        b'\x05\x0e\x07\t\x04\x01\x05\x07\x08',
    ),
    (
        b'\n\x0f\n\t\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x07\x06', # 450 bytes series
        b'\x00\x0e\x00\x06\x07\x0c\n\x0e\x07', # also 450 bytes
        b'\x05\x0e\x07\t\x04\x01\x05\x07\x08',
    ), # 3-byte-serie tuple
]

data_flat = np.array(data, dtype=np.bytes_).reshape(-1)
np.frombuffer(data_flat, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 3, 10)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: `flatten()` performs an unnecessary copy. You can just access the arrays underlying data as a `memoryview` using `.data`: `np.frombuffer(np.array(data, dtype=np.bytes_).data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(...)`

Comment: Yes, thanks! I updated my answer to use `.reshape(-1)` instead.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely what I want! Thanks a lot.